# Fill in missing values over period by groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, missing-data

Hi I have the following dataset which consists of dates (always from period 2015-01 to 2016-05), and account and value (each account will have the period 2015-01 to 2016-05).

```
Date        Account    Value    
2015-05-01  Null       0
2015-06-01  Null       0  
2015-07-01  Null       0
2015-08-01  Null       0
2015-09-01  Null       0
2015-10-01  100        50
2015-11-01  Null       0 
2015-12-01  Null       0
2016-01-01  Null       0
2016-02-01  100        80  
2016-03-01  Null       0
2016-04-01  100        100
2016-05-01  Null       0
2015-05-01  200        200
2015-06-01  Null       0  
2015-07-01  Null       0
2015-08-01  Null       0
2015-09-01  Null       0
2015-10-01  200        50
2015-11-01  Null       0 
2015-12-01  Null       0
2016-01-01  Null       0
2016-02-01  200        80  
2016-03-01  Null       0
2016-04-01  200        100
2016-05-01  Null       0
```

I would like to fill in the Null and 0's so that for the period 2015-01 to 2016-05 the same account no will appear while in that period (Please see table below). I would also like to change the value so that it is filled with the previous value if there is one available (as for account 200) or the next value (as account 100)

```
Date        Account    Value    
2015-05-01  100        50
2015-06-01  100        50  
2015-07-01  100        50
2015-08-01  100        50
2015-09-01  100        50
2015-10-01  100        50
2015-11-01  100        50 
2015-12-01  100        50
2016-01-01  100        50
2016-02-01  100        80  
2016-03-01  100        80
2016-04-01  100        100
2016-05-01  100        100
2015-05-01  200        200
2015-06-01  200        200
2015-07-01  200        200
2015-08-01  200        200
2015-09-01  200        200
2015-10-01  200        50
2015-11-01  200        50
2015-12-01  200        50
2016-01-01  200        50
2016-02-01  200        80  
2016-03-01  200        80  
2016-04-01  200        100
2016-05-01  200        100
```

Any assistance will greatly be appreciated!

Comment: You presented your data as if there is an order, while in fact the records are actually stored in the database unordered.  Is there an actual column which can impose the order you showed us?

Comment: The accounts are sorted from small to large, and each account has the dates from 2015-01 to 2016-05 assigned to them. Other than that there is no order or column that indicates order (Hope I understood your question correctly?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This should work for your input data when the table name is "test_account" and I renamed the columns to date_month,account_id and value_account.

In the table dates are dates from 1.5.2015 to 1.5.2016 as in your example

```
with date_intervals as 
(
select a.*,
nvl(lag(date_month) over (partition by account_id order by date_month     asc),'01.01.1999') as start_date,
lead(date_month) over (partition by account_id order by date_month asc)     as end_date
from  test_account a 
where account_id is not null
)
select a.date_month,b.account_id,b.value_account 
from dates a 
join     date_intervals b on (a.date_month>b.start_date and     a.date_month<=b.date_month) 
or (a.date_month>b.date_month and end_date is null)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have another form of ID except the account. Would it be possible to use row numbers seeing that the time period is constant for each account (thus the number of rows are constant for each account?)

Comment: I would suggest to re-create your table if you know that every account have the same time periods. Select only those rows where account and value is not null and from these rows you can recreate the whole table by cross joining on a dummy table with your periods.

Comment: Can you perhaps illustrate with a short example please? If I understand you correctly that is what I did initially, hence why I ended up with the NULL fields

Comment: Thank you so very much!! It works 100%! I am working in SQL server so I just replaced the NVL function with an ISNULL function, but other than that it is flawless!